# How to write a jQuery animate in this situation?

Tags: jquery, animation

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(".font1").click(function(){
  jQuery(".div21").animate({"right": "+=200px"}, "slow");
});
</script>
<a href="#" class="click">
<div class="div11" style="float:left;">
<h1 class="font1" style="z-index:5;">text1</h1>
<div class="div12">
<div class="div13"> 
<img src="img1.jpg">
<b class="effect" style="z-index:10;"></b>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="click">
<div class="div21" style="float:right;">
<h1 class="font2" style="z-index:5;">text2</h1>
<div class="div22">
<div class="div23">
<img src="img2.jpg">
<b class="effect" style="z-index:10;"></b>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need a jquery animation. When I click img1.jpg, img2.jpg will animate right 200px, but I have too many divs and other html elements, I tried many times, it also failed. How to write correctly?

**PS:** H1, the font is on the top of the image, and b class="effect" is some fadein effect, it should be the toppest of the all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add position:relative to the style attribute of div21 in order for it to animate the 'right' value.

```
<div class="div21" style="float:right; position:relative;">
```

Alternatively, you can also set the position to absolute and the right value to 0 initially.

```
<div class="div21" style="position:absolute; right: 0;">
```

Also, if the event handler is never being called, try wrapping your binding function in an anonymous function and passing it in to jQuery so it gets called after jQuery is loaded.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".font1").click(function() {
    ...
    });
});
```

As another note, you are missing the closing anchor tag `</a>` at the end of your example.